# Google Yolo / One Tap `hint` and `retrieve` do the same thing on the current project

Tags: google-api, google-signin, google-identity, google-smartlockpasswords

I have 2 projects using Google's one tap login, in one of them retrieve works as expected, if the the user was signed in before it will just go through and give the token right away

But on my current project retrieve just does the same thing as hint and always lists the users

Calling it like this:

```
await googleyolo.hint/retrieve({
  supportedAuthMethods: ['https://accounts.google.com'],
  supportedIdTokenProviders: [
    {
      uri: 'https://accounts.google.com',
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, // gets set by webpack
    },
  ],
});
```

Any help figuring this out would be appreciated

*PS: if this reaches anyone at google, could you optimize the assets some more, it seems to load around 100KB gzipped*